# Как сделать border style c помощью кругов на css?

Tags: html, css, css3, вёрстка, svg

Как сделать границу кружочками на `css`, как на картинке, не используя при этом повторяющееся изображение круга, но при этом, чтобы при различном размере экрана количество кружков отличалось?

Кроссбраузерность приветствуется.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `border: 5px dotted #fff;`???

Comment: Нет такого. Есть dotted, но стандарт не оговаривает форму «точек», могут быть круглые, могут быть квадратные. Лучше, наверное, использовать border-image https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/border-image/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Варианты, которыми я пользовался:

**1. Градиентом:**

https://caniuse.com/#search=radial-gradient

```css
.block {
  width: 200px;
  padding: 20px;
  background: 
   radial-gradient(circle at center, red 60%, transparent 61%) top left/10px 10px repeat-x,
   radial-gradient(circle at center, green 60%, transparent 61%) bottom left/10px 10px repeat-x;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">Пример с градиентом</div>
```

**2. С картинкой**, как было предложено в комментарии. Но лучше не png, как в примере, а svg:

https://caniuse.com/#feat=border-image

```css
.block2 {
  border-width: 0 0 13px 0;
  border-style: dotted;
  border-color: #d57e00;
  border-image-source: url("https://cl.ly/3c2J3c0l3r0P/dots.svg");
  border-image-slice: 33% 33%;
  border-image-repeat: round;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="block2">Пример с картинкой SVG</h1>
```

---

Не сильно силен в вёрстке, но думаю ещё есть варианты.

Answer (score 3):

### Решение SVG

Используя широкую строку и атрибут `stroke-linecap="round"`, а также `stroke-dasharray="0, stroke-width"`, где первый параметр - (черта), равен нулю, а второй параметр (пробел) равен ширине строки

#1. Получим нужный эффект:

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="50%" height="50%" viewBox="0 0 400 50"> 
    <path d="M20,25 L390,25" fill="none" stroke="red"  stroke-dasharray="0, 10" stroke-width="10" stroke-linecap="round"  />
    
</svg>
```

Так как этот метод получился универсальный, потому что идет работа только с параметрами строки, его можно использовать для любой фигуры SVG

#2. Например квадрат

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="50%" height="50%" viewBox="0 0 300 300"> 
    <rect x="20" y="20" width="260" height="260" fill="none" stroke="Limegreen"  stroke-dasharray="0, 14" stroke-width="15" stroke-linecap="round"/>
</svg>
```

#3. Круглая рамка вокруг изображения

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
   xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="50%" height="50%" viewBox="0 0 300 300"> 
     <defs>
        <pattern id="img1" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="300" height="300">
            <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/WzerI.jpg" x="0" y="-5"
                width="400" height="400" />
        </pattern>
    </defs>
 <g fill="url(#img1)">
    <circle cx="150" cy="150" r="110"  stroke="gold"  stroke-dasharray="0, 15" stroke-width="15" stroke-linecap="round"  />
    </g>    
</svg>
```